# Any way to make Google Analytics' "In-Page Analytics" show external link traffic?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Is there any way to make Google Analytics' "In-Page Analytics" show external link traffic?

As it is, pageviews for external links are showing up in the traffic reports, but not the in-page analytics.

We're using links like this:

```
 <a target="_blank" id="waitPanel" href="http://externallinkhere.com" onClick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('Header Ext Link')">Button Text</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't do it.

The in-Page Reports tries to find the links on the page. So if you're sending this "Header Ext Link" GA will understand that this is a url and will try to find that url in one of the links href attribute in the page. Of course it never will.

Comment: So theoretically if I set the 'Header Ext Link' to the same as the href, it would work?

Comment: No. Because it will try to concatenate that with the domain you registered when you created your account. And that will look something like this: `www.mysite.com/www.outersite.com`. So it will search the page for links like this, and will find none.